# Ошибка прокрутки при использовании компонента ListView

Tags: getview, android, java

На активити добавил листВью, при большом количестве элементов, при скроллинге, выделяются *все* элементы. Хотелось бы убрать этот эффект =)

[image: обычный вид]

[image: при попытке прокрутки пальцем]

```
    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> implements OnClickListener, OnCreateContextMenuListener {

 private List<Task> tasks;

 public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Task> tasks) {
  super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, tasks);
  this.tasks = tasks;

 }

 static class ViewHolder {
         public TextView title, 
             timeField;
         public Date dateStart;
         public Date dateFinish;     
         public ImageView icon;
 }

 Task task;
 ViewHolder holder;
 long time;
 ArrayList<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  task = tasks.get(position);


  View view = convertView;

  if (view == null) {

   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);

   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.subj_icon);
   holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
   holder.timeField = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.start_date);
   view.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
  }
//  view.setTag(holder);
  view.setTag(R.id.progressBar, task);
   holder.title.setText(task.getTitle()); 
  holder.timeField.setText(Utility.formatDate(task.getDateStart()) + " - " + Utility.formatDate(task.getDateEnd()));

  view.setOnClickListener(this);
  updateIcon();

  return view;
 }

 public void updateIcon() {
  int i = task.getPriority();
  int excellent = task.getComplet(); 
  if (excellent != 100) {
   switch (i) {
   case 0:
    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_rating_star_off_normal);
    break;
   case 1:
    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_rating_star_off_pressed);
    break;
   case 2:
    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_rating_star_off_selected);
    break;
   default:
    break;
   }
  } else {
   switch (i) {
   case 0:
    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_rating_star_on_normal);
    break;
   case 1:
    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_rating_star_on_pressed);
    break;
   case 2:
    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_rating_star_on_selected);
    break;
   default:
    break;
   }
  }
 }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), TaskActivity.class);  
        intent.putExtra(IDKeys.UID, ((Task)v.getTag(R.id.progressBar)).getID());
     getContext().startActivity(intent);  

 }
 /****************************************************************************************
  * 
  *  Context Menu 
  * 
  ****************************************************************************************/

    public static final int IDM_DELETE = 102;
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
   ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
     menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "DELETE");
 }

}
```

**UPD.1**

1. на рис.1 (со звездочками) - ListView, (прилагается его код)
2. при попытке его прокрутить пальцем на экрана девайса(или в эмуляторе), получаем -результат, на рис. 2. Т.е. все элементы выделяются, как один

Comment: Приложите чуточку Вашего кода. А то не совсем понятно.
То, что я вижу по скриншоту - у Вас просто не отрисовываются называния.

Comment: названия отрисовываются, черный цвет - это все элементы выделены, я думал просто выделение при нажатии на элемент убрать, но пока не получается, причина этого я думаю, потому, что на активити находится листВью, и это считается как 1 элемент, который выделяется полностью, а не отдельно по item-у

Comment: Честного говоря, пытался минуты 3 понять, что у вас происходит и так не понял:) Опишите текстом подробнее. Неочевидно как-то...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подставил на свой row_layout.xml фон - эффект пропал....

Answer (score 0):

Раз у вас одна и та же картинки в нескольких элементах, то по идеи один и тот же элемент списка используется там, попробуйте убрать вообще ViewHolder, а параметру view всегда ставить null, чтобы вьюха создавалась заново. Такие мысли. Хз, из-за этого ли косяк, но попробовать стоит.

Comment: черный цвет появляется при выделении, т.е. там все нормально отрисовывается, на скринах не видно текста, изза того что он сливается с черным, но если поставить цвет текста красный - это видн

Answer (score 0):

android:cacheColorHint=»#00000000"
Нужно добавить в xml ListView